# trying to use combobox populated from mysql to send the $id to a second page to be used in a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, combobox

Trying to use ComboBox populated from mysql to send the $id to a second page to be used in a query to populate data.

Here is my code sitting in the bootsrap nav bar on page 1

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left"  action='customerpage.php' method='post'>
<div class="form-group">
<select type="submit" id="navbarcustomer" class="form-control" name='customerid' placeholder="Customer Lookup">
<option>Customer Lookup</option>
<?php

require ('dbconnect.php');
$result = $con->query("select id, lastname, firstname from customer");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['lastname'];
$firstname = $row['firstname']; 

echo '<option value="/customerpage.php?id='.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';


}

echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?> 
</div>

</form>
```

here is my code on page to that needs to receive the $id variable to be used in the query

```
<?php


$id = $_GET['custid'];
echo $id;
require ('dbconnect.php');


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=' . $id . '");
//$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=$id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['firstname'];

echo "<br>";
  }

?>
```

Please help the name of page 2 is `/customerpage.php` Thank you.

Comment: You're using `?id` and `$_GET['custid']` - That should be `$_GET['id']` - Use `isset()` and error reporting.

Comment: it didnt work out. how can i check if the data is being send?

Comment: This may be another issue `WHERE id=' . $id . '");` you can try `WHERE id='" . $id . "'");` or `($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=$id")`

Comment: You may also need to set your `</form>` before you close your DB connection.

Comment: Your select is named `name="customerid"`, and your form method is `merhod="post"`, so you need `$id = $_POST['customerid'];` not `$id = $_GET['custid'];`. Also, your value is going to be sent as `/customerpage.php?id=ID`, not just `ID`, so you should change your option to `echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've set it up so that when you click the dropdown, it will automatically go to the customers page. We will need just a little bit of JavaScript for that.

Place this below your closing `</form>` tag, but preferably right before you closing `</body>` tag  document.

```
<script>
var navbarcustomer = document.getElementById('navbarcustomer');

navbarcustomer.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  window.location = this.value;
});
</script>
```

If you're using jQuery, you can OPTIONALLY use this in your `<script>` tags instead of the code above:

```
$('#navbarcustomer').on('change', function () {
  window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

Next, you need to make sure your GET vars match what you're sending it. Change `$_GET` variable to look like this, as you are providing `id=` in the query string (and not `custid=`):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Edit:
There are a few more things that need to be addressed. Also in the `customerpage.php`, your query is little broken. You can use something like to fetch your records, it's a little bit cleaner:

```
$id = (int) $id; // cast to integer to prevent SQL injection.
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = $id");

// there is only going to be 1 record so we don't need the while loop.
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

echo $row['firstname'];
echo $row['lastname'];
```

Comment: There are a few more issues in here that I am seeing, Fred pointed out an issue with the MySQL query in `customerpage.php` - this absolutely wont work unless that's fixed as well. I've updated my post with that fix.

Comment: bam your the man !! Thanks Sam me and the monitor were gonna have a fist fight lol